# Most natural way of saying "What is this for?" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, oral

Like if you pick up an unfamiliar tool in a hardware store and ask the clerk "What is this for?"

What would be a common way of phrasing that?

Answer (score 3):

The first expression that comes to me is:

> À quoi ça sert ?
> Ça sert à quoi ?

You could also say:

> À quoi cela sert-il ?
>
> Quel est l'utilité/l'usage de cet objet ?

Comment: You might add the usual spoken French: *Ça sert à quoi ?*

Comment: Is there any chance of this coming across as a rhetorical question? "What a useless object."

Comment: @jlliagre: Effectivement,  je l'ai ajouté.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: Désolé, je ne comprends pas bien ce que tu veux dire.

Comment: Toto: I think that @LukeSawczak is asking whether saying "ça sert à quoi ?" can come across as questioning whether the object has any use at all. As in, you'd say "ça sert à quoi ?" in a sarcastic tone to imply that this has no use. And to answer the question, Luke: yes, it can come across that way, but as with all spoken sentences, the tone is key. If you say it in an interrogative manner, it won't. If you say it in a demeaning manner, it will. If you say "à quoi ça sert *ce truc/machin* ?" for example it's much more likely to come across as rhetorical.

Comment: @Najib Merci ! One thing that complicates it is the French question tone being a little different from English, making it harder for me to convey the sincerity/rhetoricalness of a question...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

> What is this used for?

may, among other ways, be translated by

> À quoi est-ce que ça sert ?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/what-s-this-used-for

Strangely linguee.fr does not have any relevant example.

https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=What+is+this+used+for%3F

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, were you correcting my phrasing? I'm not sure what the difference is supposed to be between "What is this for" and "What is this used for"....both are ordinary and correct, and the former is probably more common.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to insult you. I make a mistake. I was thinking about what is it for and not what is this for. Of course you are correct.

Comment: @Aerovistae I made the correction. I apologize again. I think now everything is ok.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean to be abrasive. I see what you meant now.

Comment: @Aerovistae: No problem:-)!